# How to disable images in Firefox push notifications?

Tags: firefox, notifications

I want to hide the images from Firefox push notifications. Just text. No image.

I'm doing it because the images are usually huge compared to the text and they end up taking half of my monitor (1024x768) for two lines of text.

I don't want to completely disable pushes. Just want to make them smaller.

Notification test: http://www.bennish.net/web-notifications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you can be selective about the content of the
push notifications, which seem to be an all-or-nothing proposition.

You can
[revoke Web Push permissions for a specific site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox#w_how-do-i-revoke-web-push-permissions-for-a-specific-site)
which is overusing this feature.
You may even
[disable Web Push completely](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox#w_how-do-i-disable-web-push-completely).